# find value in data.frame using dates

Tags: r

I want to select a number that is connected with a date that is not in the list. So as an example:

```
value = c("4","10","11","6")
date = c("1989-11-12","1990-05-09", "1991-08-15", "1992-06-23")
df <- data.frame(value,date)

> df
 value   date
1  4 1989-11-12
2 10 1990-05-09
3 11 1991-08-15
4 16 1992-06-23
```

In other words: 'if you were born between 1989-11-12 and 1990-05-09 than the value is equal to 4.'
Now I need to find the value of the date: 1990-10-13. So I want the output to be equal to 10.
What I tried:

```
> df$a[df$b=="1991-0-15"]
character(0)
```

But that's incorrect. Can somebody help me with this question?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Would you please explain in more detail what you are trying to achieve? Also, I do not see a `list` here, what did you actually mean?

Comment: One possible interpretation of your question is that any date entered that has no value in the original dataframe should return the value of the datapoint immediately preceding it in time. Is that what you mean? If not, could you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: Yess! that's what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `findInterval` -

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
input <- as.Date('1990-10-13')
df$value[findInterval(input, df$date, left.open = TRUE)]
#[1] "10"
```

`left.open` is `TRUE` since you mentioned that if a date is `1990-05-09` it should return 4 and not 10.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `cut` from `base R`

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
input <- as.Date("1990-10-13")
df$value[match(as.Date(cut(input, breaks = df$date)), df$date)]
#[1] "10"
```